# Add style to table column

Tags: html, css

I am working with a (10X3) table on the HTML page. And in the heading of the table, any one of the column header (**not pre-decided so I can't use the column number, it could be any column**) contains a CSS class named "preferred". In these case, is there any way in which I can add style to the whole column whose  contains the "preferred" class?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

This is how the code looks like.

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th class="preferred"></th> <!-- style should be applied here -->
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> <!-- style should be applied here -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td><!-- style should be applied here -->
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share some code. It will make solving things easier

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui sure

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo-selectors:

```css
td, tr {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

:where(td,th):last-child {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Test 1 </th>
    <th> Test 2 </th>
    <th> Test 3 </th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Since you don't know what column it will be on, you'll be needing some JS. This is assuming only one column will need to be highlighted

```js
const thList = document.querySelectorAll('th');
let colNumber = 0;
for (let i=0; i<thList.length; i++) {
  if (thList[i].classList.contains('preferred')) {
    colNumber = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}

const targetList = document.querySelectorAll(`tr > td:nth-child(${colNumber})`)

targetList.forEach(cell => {
  cell.classList.add('preferred')
})
```

```css
td, th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.preferred {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th> Test 1 </th>
        <th> Test 2 </th>
        <th class="preferred"> Test 3 </th>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
        <td> data </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the updated JS to make this code work for multiple columns:

```
const thList = document.querySelectorAll('th');
let colNumber = [];
let targetList;
for (let i=0; i<thList.length; i++) {
  if (thList[i].classList.contains('preferred')) {
    targetList = document.querySelectorAll(`tr > td:nth-child(${i+1})`)
  }
  targetList.forEach(cell => {
    cell.classList.add('preferred')
  }) 
}
```

Comment: That's the thing, class preferred is added by the backend as the page is loaded, so it's not necessarily the last column

Comment: it should be the one that contains the "preferred" class. I don't know the column number beforehand.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read that part in the question

Comment: That's totally okay :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo class. You'll need to use some JS to get the index of the column:

```js
const column = document.querySelector('.preferred')
const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(column.parentNode.querySelectorAll('th'), column);
document.head.innerHTML+=`<style>td:nth-child(${index+1}), .preferred{background-color:green;}`;
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Test 1 </th>
    <th> Test 2 </th>
    <th class="preferred"> Test 3 </th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
    <td> data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The column number not pre-decided so I can't use the column number beforehand. Class preferred is added by the backend as the page is loaded, so it's not necessarily the last column

Answer (score -1):

To get the **index** of a specific TH with class `"preferred"` you could use a simple function like:

```js
const getPreferredColIndex = (EL) => {
  const THs = EL.querySelectorAll("thead th");
  return [...THs].findIndex(TH => TH.classList.contains("preferred"));
};
```

Having that index you could than create another function that **highlights the column**:

```js
const makeColPreferred = (EL, i) => {
  if (i === undefined) i = getPreferredColIndex(EL);
  const PR = EL.querySelectorAll(".preferred");
  PR.forEach(EL => EL.classList.remove("preferred")); // Remove from all
  EL.querySelectorAll(`th:nth-child(${i+1}), td:nth-child(${i+1})`).forEach(EL => EL.classList.add("preferred"));
};
```

Finally you could use that latter like:

```js
// Will automatically detect the preferred based on TH with class "preferred"
makeColPreferred(myTable);
```

Or even if you want to manually set / change (like on CLICK) to another one use:

```js
// Dynamically change to another column index:
makeColPreferred(myTable, 0); // will make col index 0 preferred
makeColPreferred(myTable, 1); // will make col index 1 preferred
// You got the point
```

Example:

```js
const getPreferredColIndex = (EL) => {
  const THs = EL.querySelectorAll("thead th");
  return [...THs].findIndex(TH => TH.classList.contains("preferred"));
};

const makeColPreferred = (EL, i) => {
  if (i === undefined) i = getPreferredColIndex(EL);
  const PR = EL.querySelectorAll(".preferred");
  PR.forEach(EL => EL.classList.remove("preferred")); // Remove from all
  EL.querySelectorAll(`th:nth-child(${i+1}), td:nth-child(${i+1})`).forEach(EL => EL.classList.add("preferred"));
};

const TABLE = document.querySelector("table"); // PS: be more specific than "table"!
makeColPreferred(TABLE);
// makeColPreferred(TABLE, 1); // Specifically set to index 1
```

```css
.preferred {background: #ffe59a;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>th1</th>
      <th>th2</th>
      <th class="preferred">th3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```